# file not found exception in getAssets() method

Tags: java, android, xml, filenotfoundexception

Im trying to open the xml file from assets folder...but it is throwing "FileNotFoundException" please help!!!

```
try {
    InputStream is = getAssets().open(MainActivity.pass);
            ............
            ...........
   }
   //value of "MainActivity.pass"=sreb.xml
```

sreb.xml is present in assets folder in .xml format

"MainAcivity.pass" is in String value only , i too checked that

"MainActivity" is other class in that "pass" is a static String value...

try block is in Activity only

what's the mistake ??

Comment: try     `InputStream is = getAssets().open("sreb.xml")` instead of static string and if you need to pass string from one activity to another use intent

Comment: Do a `Log.d("TAG", MainActivity.pass)` just before the `getAssets` line. Then please show us the logcat.

Comment: try to add prefix backslash `MainActivity.pass="/sreb.xml"`

Answer (score 1):

Things you can check:

- Start with the simple things: Is the line throwing the exception really the line you look at? Take a close look in logcat to check.
- Is the file to be opened really spelled correctly? Do a `Log.d("TAG", "|" + MainActivity.pass + "|")` and compare the name between the `"|"`, including any spaces, to be exactly the same as in the assets folder.
- Do you look in the correct assets folder? The following code gives you a list of the existing files in the asset folder you look at and print them to logcat, seperated by comma and space. Is your file in there?

  ```
  try {
      Log.d("TAG", Arrays.toString(getAssets().list(".")));
  } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("TAG", e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
  }
  ```